# Calling a function when a row is highlighted in Listview

Tags: android

I know that when a row is selected in list view, the function onListItemClick() is called.

I want to know which function is called when a row in ListView is highlighted(not selected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that when a row is selected in
>   list view, the function
>   onListItemClick() is called.

No, that is called when a row is clicked, and only if you are using a `ListActivity`.

> I want to know which function is
>   called when a row in ListView is
>   highlighted(not selected).

Highlighted and selected are the same thing. Use `setOnItemSelectedListener()` on your `ListView`.